# Pylint reporting Cyclic Import on file without imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pylint

So `Pylint` (`1.4.3`) is reporting a Cyclic Import and it doesn't make much sense.
First of all, the file that's report has no import statements.

Second of all no files import the reference file. a `__init__.py` file loads configuration values from `development_config` (file in question) but no files
import said file.

So why is Pylint giving me this warning?

## Pylint warning

```
************* Module heart_beat.development_config
R:  1, 0: Cyclic import (heart_beat -> heart_beat.views -> heart_beat.models) (cyclic-import)
R:  1, 0: Cyclic import (heart_beat -> heart_beat.views) (cyclic-import)
```

## `development_config`

```
""" -------------------------- DATA BASE CONFINGURATION --------------------"""
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False

""" -------------------------- Flask Application Config --------------------"""
THREADS_PER_PAGE = 8
VERSION = "0.1"
```

## `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

#from register_assets import register_all

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

# the environment variable LIMBO_SETTINGS is set in runserver, run_unit_tests
# or limbo.wsgi.

def load_configs():
    """Take all configs found in development_config.py."""
    app.config.from_pyfile("development_config.py", silent=False)

load_configs()

# global SQLAlchemy configuration
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#Create and register all static asset bundles.
#register_all(app)

#NOTE: DON'T LISTEN TO YOUR IDE! heart_beat.views is used and required.
import heart_beat.views  # views contains all URL routes, Importing sets routes.
def setup_db():
    """Database creation in a file rather then a statement for easier tests."""
    db.create_all()

def teardown_db():
    """Database deletion in a file rather then a statement for easier tests."""
    db.drop_all()

setup_db()
```

## `views.py`

```
from flask import request

from . import app
from . import db
from . import models
from . import exceptions as ex
```

## `models.py`

```
import datetime

from . import exceptions
from . import db
from . import app
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it's calling out development_config specifically, but you do have circular imports for sure (app (`__init__.py`) imports views, views imports app). Generally in flask one would use blueprints to define views in separate files. This large flask project has really good organization, it's worth looking at: https://github.com/masom/bluemonk

Answer (score 16):

I believe this is currently a bug in pylint. Things that require analysis over multiple modules (for example `cyclic-import` and `duplicate-code` detection) get thrown as refactors into the last-parsed module file. For me, this ended up being an empty `__init__.py` file that had both of these dropped into it.

Both of these refactor messages though contain the actual module names which are problematic:

- For cyclic-import, the problematic modules are listed in the parenthesis
- For duplicate-code, the problematic  modules are listed on the following lines starting with `==`

The grouping of these is not limited to the print-out of modules, it also effects the summary report `% errors / warnings by module` in which that final parsed file gets the counts for the refactors and none of the modules it actually concerns get any counts from them.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable those false positives without totally disabling `cyclic-import` and `duplicate-code`?